# XNA saving a single tile as PNG

Tags: c#, xna

I have another problem with XNA. I have a Texture2D containing many tiles. Then i have a list of rectangles which are supposed to be the bounds of each 50x50 pixels tile.

Now I would like to be able to save any tile as a small PNG-file.
Here is my code:

```
//declare the rectangles and spritesets
Texture2D tileSheet;
List<Rectangle> tileSet;

//load every tile, also works great
tileSheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Tiles/Object");
int noOfTilesX = (int)tileSheet.Width / 50;
int noOfTilesY = (int)tileSheet.Height / 50;
tileSet = new List<Rectangle>(noOfTilesX * noOfTilesY);
for (int j = 0; j < noOfTilesY; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTilesX; i++)
    {
        bounds = new Rectangle(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
        tileSet.Add(bounds);
    }
}

//save as pngs if they do not exist
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Test.png"))
{
    Stream stream = File.Create(@"C:\Test.png");
    //works, but it is only the complete file, i'd like to save a single tile
    tileSheet.SaveAsPng(stream, tileSheet.Width, tileSheet.Height);
}
```

The problem is: I cannot save a single tile, it always saves my whole Texture2D and stretches it to the resolution i pass in the parameters. Searching in the internet didn't tell me anything, it just told me how to use the stream for a complete texture2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a question where someone wanted a new texture by taking a part of a larger texture, much like your tile-problem.

You can use this extension method and then save the result like you would do normally:

```
public static class TextureExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new texture from an area of the texture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics">The current GraphicsDevice</param>
    /// <param name="rect">The dimension you want to have</param>
    /// <returns>The partial Texture.</returns>
    public static Texture2D CreateTexture(this Texture2D src, GraphicsDevice graphics, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(graphics, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        int count = rect.Width * rect.Height;
        Color[] data = new Color[count];
        src.GetData(0, rect, data, 0, count);
        tex.SetData(data);
        return tex;
    }
}
```

Suggested usage:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("path"))
{
    tileTexture.CreateTexture(GraphicsDevice, new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)).SaveAsJpeg(stream, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I haven't tested it so there might be some errors, but you just need to create a separate texture for each tile and then save each of them.

```
//declare the rectangles and spritesets
Texture2D tileSheet;
List<Rectangle> tileSet;

//load every tile, also works great
tileSheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Tiles/Object");
int noOfTilesX = (int)tileSheet.Width / 50;
int noOfTilesY = (int)tileSheet.Height / 50;
tileSet = new List<Rectangle>(noOfTilesX * noOfTilesY);

// Gets the color data of the tile sheet.
Color[] tileSheetPixels = new Color[tileSheet.Width * tileSheet.Height];
tileSheetPixels.GetData<Color>(tileSheetPixels);

for (int j = 0; j < noOfTilesY; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfTilesX; i++)
    {
        bounds = new Rectangle(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
        tileSet.Add(bounds);

        // Creates a new texture for a single tile.
        Texture2D singleTile = new Texture2D(graphics, 50, 50);
        Color[] pixels = new Color[50 * 50];

        // Gets the pixels that correspond to the single tile and saves them in another
        // color array.
        for (int k = 0; k < pixels.Length; k++)
        {
            pixels[k] = new Color();

            int x = bounds.X;
            x += (k % 50);
            int y = bounds.Y;
            y += (k / 50);

            pixels[k] = tileSheetPixels[y * 50 + x];
        }

        // Sets the color data of the single tile texture to the color array
        // created above.
        singleTile.SetData<Color>(pixels);

        //save as pngs if they do not exist
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\tile_" + i + "_" + j + ".png"))
        {
            Stream stream = File.Create(@"C:\tile_" + i + "_" + j + ".png");

            singleTile.SaveAsPng(stream, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```